# Computer Graphics is graduating!

Tags: discussion

Six years after starting our [public beta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74985/computer-graphics), we're moving on up! We get to stay!

Some things will change:

1. We lose the "beta" designation on the site name
2. We will have an election (existing moderators will need to run or stand again)
3. We become eligible for question migration with other sites on the network
4. We will be able to choose Community Ads (is this true? --droog)

Some things will not change:

1. We will keep the "beta level" privilege levels, so nobody loses privileges
2. We won't get a new design (yet)

We would like to thank you, the community, for making this possible. Because of all your great contributions we are now going to be a permanent part of the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presto!

It is done.

Comment: We are finally there :)

Comment: I asked on MSE if there's [anything we should do now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374186/our-site-just-graduated-do-we-need-to-do-anything)